# Sync Google Contacts in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, contacts, google-sync, google

I am having trouble with keeping my Contacts sync'd with my Google Apps account. In "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" there is no Contacts option:

[image]

In the contacts program, I did get it to sync by checking synchronize with Google under "On My Mac":

[image]

However, when I add a contact in Google after this it never seems to update the contacts in OS X with the new contact.

Comment: Might be worth trying to set up the Google account [as an Exchange account](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) like on iOS.

Comment: I guess the problem is for "Google Apps" account. Kyle, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got small trick: uncheck "Synchronize with Google" and recheck it.

Or

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have been setting up a new Mac with 10.8 today and have noticed a similar issue. So far I've found that temporarily enabling iCloud contacts sync in System Prefs, then disabling it and going back to Google sync within Contacts seems to have got things moving again.

Answer (score 3):

For Google Apps accounts, Google suggests using the CardDAV protocol. See the instructions here:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1366863

Here is a copy&past.

Use CardDAV to sync contacts on your Mac with your Google Contacts.

1. On your Mac, go to Applications > Contacts.
2. In the Contacts application, go to Contacts > Preferences > Accounts > +
3. In the window that pops up, enter the following:

   Account type: CardDAV

   Username: (Your username at your domain, for example: john@solarmora.com)

   Password: (Your password)

   Server address: google.com

You contacts will now start syncing from your Google account with your Mac. Any new contacts you make on your Mac will sync with your Google account, and any new contacts in your Google account will sync with your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Sync using the CardDAV protocol. It's easy, really good and works much better than Exchange!

Go to preferences in the Mac Contacts app and add a new account using CardDAV.

Instructions on the correct inputs can be found at: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2753077

(P.S. I know this help page is for iOS, but the details also work for the Mac Contacts app.)

Comment: Links may break over time. Please summarize the content of your link. ;)

Comment: Nice idea, but not sure this works. I get an HTTP error from the server instead of contacts (with SSL enabled). In particular if you have Google already added (e.g. for calendars) it seems to merge / overwrite some things apple tried to prevent, and can corrupt this & other sync options. Terrible software from Apple this time.